# UIPanrecognizer cancelled by subviews

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, subview

I have this view -'card'- with UIPanrecognizer and an action attached to that.

Works as expected.

here's the action code:

```
  @IBAction func swipe(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let card = sender.view!
        let point = sender.translation(in: view)
        card.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + point.x, y: view.center.y + point.y)
        if sender.state == .ended{
            print("dropped")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {card.center = self.view.center})
        }
    }
```

However, my view has several subviews.

it looks like this:
[image]

If I start a panning gesture on one of the subviews, the gesture quite often misbehaves.

The misbehaviour I observe is that while I'm dragging around the view, when having initiated the gesture on a subview, the view doesn't consistently follow my finger, but just jumps back -at seemingly random moments and locations- to its original position. As you can see, I log when the gesture is ended. When the view jumps back, that log is not printed.

I have set User Interaction Enabled to false on all subviews

Is there a way to tell the subviews to pass the gesture to the view without interfering?

Comment: You need to add more details to your post explaining what your code is doing, and what you mean by *"misbehaves"*. Ideally, a [mre].

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @matt I AM using auto layout. Does that explain things?

Comment: It might. You are changing the center but the constraints still say use the old center.

Comment: Somehow this only happens on subviews, not on the view itself. But how should I decouple the 'real' center from the constrained center? Isn't a center just a center, regardless of how it came to existence?

Comment: To clarify... are you talking about dragging a ***view that has subviews***? Or, do you mean you have several "card" views starting at different positions, and when you stop dragging any card you want it to animate to the center of the screen (`self.view`)?

Comment: @DonMag: I added an image to the question above for clarification. 
I have been logging several values: 'view.center' is a fixed value (as expected) and 'point' is changing with the gesture. So basically, the UI is not updating correctly. Why?

Comment: @Sjakelien - I think you really need to create a [mre] and post it to GitHub (or similar) so we can see what's going on. I laid this out - a blue `UIView` with a label in each corner... and I can drag the view around (animates back to center when I stop dragging) without problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC3ho.png

Comment: @DonMag Thank you so much for your concern. I took my project, and took out all the 'irrelevant' stuff to share it with you...and the problem disappeared. I will now one by one add the apparently not too irrelevant things to see where the problem is introduced. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Sjakelien - while you may have solved the issue, *"I'm not sure if I understand iy"* is probably not ideal. If you share your minimal project that demonstrates the problem (that is, with the constraints that were causing it), we should be able to give you an explanation.

Comment: @DonMag I hoped the screen shot in the answer would contain all the necessary information. At this point, I'm not able anymore to recreate the offensive constraints.
So, at least the value of this all is, that "faulty constraints can interfere with gestures". Apologies for this somehow unsatisfactory result.

Answer (score 0):

While this is the answer, I'm not sure if I understand it:

One of the subviews, 'badge' had some auto layout constraints that caused the misbehavior.

I removed the constraints and redefined them in a more thoughtful way, and the problem disappeared.

I hope some of you can explain what happened. Thanks for all your involvement!

PS: reviewing the other constraints as well now...

[image]